# .htaccess REQUEST_URI without slash

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=123.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.456.com/index/&%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,P]`
```

How to remove the slash for `REQUEST_URI`?

Current result: http://www.456.com/index&/pages=gallery

Comment: Why are you calling `REEQUEST_URI` when you are capturing the route anyway? Use `http://www.456.com/index/&$1`

Comment: Great, issue solved, thanks for the great help. :-)

Comment: Have posted the answer. Kindly accept for reference to others.

Answer (score 1):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` always returns with a leading slash, as all Request URIs contain slashes as they are absolute (see: [Why trailing slashes on URIs are important](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/)).

As such, you will need to use the captured group `(.*)` by passing it to the destination using `$1`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.456.com/index/&$1 [QSA,L,P]`
```